# Not sure how to write a simple query

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Hi I Have a table which has number of products and rating for each, due to some reasons I have different row of each product along with rate of each person who rated it, as following:

```
p1 2
p2 4
p3 4
p1 4
p1 5
p1 3
p2 7
```

I am using following query but it shows the average rate of all products, but I am expecting it to show the average rate of each product seperately.

```
Select ProductName, AVG(Rate) FROM Products
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `GROUP BY productName`:

```
Select ProductName, AVG(Rate) AS 'Average Rate'
FROM Products 
GROUP BY productName
```

**Edit:** To show the one with highest rate:

```
SELECT ProductName, Rate
FROM Products
ORDER BY rate DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**Edit 2:** To get the product name with the highest average rate:

```
SELECT productname, AVG(rate) Avgrate
FROM Products
GROUP BY productname 
HAVING AVG(rate) = 
(
     SELECT AVG(rate) 
     FROM Products 
     GROUP BY productname 
     ORDER BY AVG(rate) DESC
     LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks How about the one with highest rate?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Group By.

```
Select ProductName, AVG(Rate) FROM Products GROUP BY ProductName
```

**To Sort Result use Order By after Group By**

```
Select ProductName, AVG(Rate) FROM Products GROUP BY ProductName ORDER BY ProductName
```

Above query sort result in Ascending order if you want to sort descending then use `DESC`,

```
Select ProductName, AVG(Rate) FROM Products GROUP BY ProductName ORDER BY ProductName DESC
```

**To Select Higher Rating Product**

```
Select ProductName, AVG(Rate) FROM Products GROUP BY ProductName
HAVING AVG(Rate) = (SELECT MAX(AVG(Rate)) FROM Products GROUP BY ProductName)
```

This query return all product which have max average rating.

Only One Product with Higher rating use LIMIT in Descending Sort

```
 Select ProductName, AVG(Rate) FROM Products GROUP BY ProductName 
 ORDER BY ProductName DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Check out this link for information of GROUP By http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Would you also tell me how I can show the one with highest rate? also how to sort them if I am going to show all rates

Comment: check my updated answer to sort and select higher rating product.